# How to shift entire row from last to 3rd position without changing values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is my table:

```
DocumentTypeId   DocumentType    UserId       CreatedDtm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2d47e2f8-4       PDF             443f-4baa    2015-12-03 17:56:59.4170000
b4b-4803-a       Images          a99f-1fd     1997-02-11 22:16:51.7000000
600-0e32         XL              e60e07a6b    2015-08-19 15:26:11.4730000 
40f8ff9f         Word            79b399715    1994-04-23 10:33:44.2300000
8230a07c         email           750e-4c3d    2015-01-10 09:56:08.1700000
```

How can I shift the last entire row (`DocumentType=email`) on `3rd` position,(`before DocumentType=XL`) without changing table values?

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. These is no "last row". Despite their superficial resemblances, tables are nothing like spreadsheets.

Comment: In SQL tables represent *unordered* sets of data. This means there is no inherent order in any SQL table. So it makes no sense talking about positioning rows in a specific place within a table.

Comment: The **only reliable way** to get something **ordered** from a relational database is by doing a `SELECT` with an **explicit** `ORDER BY` applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Without wishing to deny the truth of what others have said here, SQL Server does have CLUSTERED indices.  For full details on these and the difference between a clustered table and a non-clustered one, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described).  In effect, a clustered table does have data written to disk in index order. However, due to subsequent insertions and deletions, you should never rely on any given record being in a fixed ordinal position.

To get your data showing email third and XL fourth, you simply need to order by CreatedDtm.  Thus:

```
declare @test table
(
DocumentTypeID varchar(20),
DocumentType varchar(10),
UserID varchar(20),
CreatedDtm datetime
)
INSERT INTO @test VALUES
('2d47e2f8-4','PDF','443f-4baa','2015-12-03 17:56:59'),
('b4b-4803-a','Images','a99f-1fd','1997-02-11 22:16:51'),
('600-0e32','XL','e60e07a6b','2015-08-19 15:26:11'),
('40f8ff9f','Word','79b399715','1994-04-23 10:33:44'),
('8230a07c','email','750e-4c3d','2015-01-10 09:56:08')

SELECT * FROM @test order by CreatedDtm
```

This gives a result set of:

```
40f8ff9f    Word    79b399715   1994-04-23 10:33:44.000
b4b-4803-a  Images  a99f-1fd    1997-02-11 22:16:51.000
8230a07c    email   750e-4c3d   2015-01-10 09:56:08.000
600-0e32    XL  e60e07a6b   2015-08-19 15:26:11.000
2d47e2f8-4  PDF 443f-4baa   2015-12-03 17:56:59.000
```

This maybe what you are looking for, but I cannot stress enough, that it only gives email 3rd and XL 4th in this particular case.  If the dates were different, it would not be so.  But perhaps, this was all that you needed?

Comment: Yes, there are clustered indexes - but SQL Server offers no guarantees that it will return rows in clustered index order (or any other order) in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause on the select.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are quite right, of course.  I should have pointed that out.  Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you need to sort by `DocumentType`column.

Joining with a temp table, which may contain virtually `DocumenTypes` with desired `SortOrder`, you can achieve the result you want.

```
declare @tbl table(
DocumentTypeID varchar(50),
DocumentType varchar(50)
)

insert into @tbl(DocumentTypeID, DocumentType)
values
('2d47e2f8-4','PDF'),
('b4b-4803-a','Images'),
('600-0e32','XL'),
('40f8ff9f','Word'),
('8230a07c','email')
;

--this will give you original output
select * from @tbl;


--this will output rows with new sort order
select t.* from @tbl t
inner join 
(
    select * 
    from 
        (values
            ('PDF',1, 1),
            ('Images',2, 2),
            ('XL',3, 4),
            ('Word',4, 5),
            ('email',5, 3) --here I put new sort order '3'
    ) as dt(TypeName, SortOrder, NewSortOrder)
) dt
on dt.TypeName = t.DocumentType
order by dt.NewSortOrder
```

Answer (score -1):

The row positions don't really matter in SQL tables, since it's all unordered sets of data, but if you really want to switch the rows I'd suggest you send all your data to temp table e.g,

```
SELECT * FROM [tablename] INTO #temptable
```

then delete/truncate the data from that table (if it won't mess the other tables it's connected to) and use the temp table you made to insert into it as you like, since it'll have all the same fields with the same data from the original.